TRYING TO TRACK WALLET ADDRESSES THAT TRADED SOME PARTICULAR SERIES OF DIFFERENT SOLANA MEME TOKEN
pls i want to write  a code that I can type on Dexscreener api(Currently i cant use their API) or any other api can use to find wallet addresses That bought series of 4 different Solana meme token
